# Can't find Backlog page anywhere in Jira version 7

Tags: jira, jira-agile

I am attempting to follow these Jira instructions to create a Sprint: https://www.atlassian.com/agile/tutorials/sprints.

The first step is to go to the Backlog page. However, even as an administrator, I cannot find the Backlog page. I have looked absolutely everywhere. Is there any non-default configuration that I need to set up in order to view the Backlog page?

In my understanding of this screenshot, all of Jira Agile is enabled (note that "Loading Screenshots" never actually loads:
[image]

Or, more generally than that, is there a different way to create a Sprint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible in Jira version 7 to create a Sprint from a **Kanban Board**, which is the board my organization is using.

Instead, I need to first create an **Agile Board** [using these instructions](https://www.atlassian.com/agile/tutorials/creating-your-agile-board). Then I can successfully follow the instructions to create a Sprint.